KivyMD MDTopAppBar not display any content
I'm trying to copy the code that is presented on the official website from the developers of MDTopAppBar:
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivymd.uix.snackbar import MDSnackbar

KV = '''
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    MDTopAppBar:
        title: "MDTopAppBar"
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: app.callback(x)]]
        right_action_items: [["dots-vertical", lambda x: app.callback(x)]]

    MDLabel:
        text: "Content"
        halign: "center"
'''


class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Orange"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        menu_items = [
            {
                "text": f"Item {i}",
                "on_release": lambda x=f"Item {i}": self.menu_callback(x),
            } for i in range(5)
        ]
        self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(items=menu_items)
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def callback(self, button):
        self.menu.caller = button
        self.menu.open()

    def menu_callback(self, text_item):
        self.menu.dismiss()
        MDSnackbar(text=text_item).open()


Test().run()

Result
i get a completely different from what is stated on the site. When trying to create something of my own whatever i try MDTopAppBar does not display any content and remains empty. What is wrong?

Firstly, if not please upgrade to the latest KivyMD version;
Secondly, read the full documentation page carefully.
As your issue is not fully described, You may use this modified code;
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivymd.uix.snackbar import Snackbar
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineIconListItem

KV = '''
MDStackLayout:
    size_hint:1,1
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        adaptive_height:True

        MDTopAppBar:
            title: "MDTopAppBar"
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: app.callback(x)]]
            right_action_items: [["dots-vertical", lambda x: app.callback(x)]]

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        adaptive_height:True
        
        MDLabel:
            text: "Content"
            halign: "center"
'''
class IconListItem(OneLineIconListItem):
    icon=StringProperty()
    divider=None

class Test(MDApp):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Indigo"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        self.menu_items = [
            {
                "viewclass": "IconListItem",
                "icon":'git',
                "text": f"Item {i}",
                "on_release": lambda x=f"Item {i}": self.menu_callback(x),
            } for i in range(5)
        ]
        
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def callback(self, button):
        self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
            items=self.menu_items,
            width_mult=4.5,
        )
        self.menu.caller = button
        self.menu.open()

    def menu_callback(self, text_item):
        self.menu.dismiss()
        Snackbar(text=text_item).open()

Test().run()

You can follow different KivyMD projects and learn efficient use of
KivyMD widgets from my youtube channel https://youtube.com/@NovfensecInc
or any other learning platform.

Code sequence in KV (kivymd 2.0) must be like this;
MDScreen:
    MDTopAppBar:
        type: "small"
        MDTopAppBarLeadingButtonContainer:
            MDActionTopAppBarButton:
                icon: "git"
        MDTopAppBarTitle:
                text: "Your button text"

Hope this helps
